# asp.net with pagemethods dont work

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a problem with the PageMethods in asp.net, i have a button that calls a JavaScript function and this function has a PageMethod that return a value from a method in my c# codebehind.
But the PageMethod does not return anything when i click the button, return the value until I click the button for second time.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="true"   CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

This is my asp.net code:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />    
    <asp:Button ID="btnViaje" runat="server" Text="Viajes"  OnClientClick="CargarViajes(); return false;" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRuta" runat="server" Text="Ruta" OnClientClick="CargarRuta(); return false;" />
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:900px;display:block;float:left"></div>
    <p id="co" style="display:block; float:left">Estadia: </p>   
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="SendA" name="SendA" />
   <button onclick="rastreo()" style="width:50px;height:20px;">rastreo</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button btnViaje call the javascript function but the response does not return anything until i click again the button :

```
 function CargarViajes() {

        PageMethods.ConvertDataTabletoString(function (response) {
            camiones = eval("(function(){return " + response + ";})()"
                );
        });
    }
```

This is my c# method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PROYECTOLALAE2\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_LALA_Rastreo_Rastreo;Integrated Security=true"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id_Viaje=idviaje, LatV=latitud, LonV=longitud, Velocidad=velocidad, In1=entrada1_dig, In2=entrada2_dig, AI1=entrada1_analoga, AI2=entrada2_analoga FROM Tb_Viaje_Coordenada", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your JavaScript like so:

```
function CargarViajes() {
    PageMethods.ConvertDataTabletoString(OnSucceeded); 
}

function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) 
{          
    if (methodName == "ConvertDataTabletoString") 
    { 
        // Now do whatever you like with results from ConvertDataTabletoString
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lucidgold that works. but i have a question if i try to put CargarViajes directly in my javascript code dont work not from a button, why?

Comment: @Jesus: I think its becuase Ajax needs/expects a certian type of response from the server-side that contains a result, userContext, and methodName. I think only then it will behaive the way you expect. From my experiance I have only seen it work this way. If my answer did help you please accept it.

Comment: sorry @lucidgold but I have no experience with asp.net. 
Could contact you by email to ask you some questions? 
I really need help with this.

Comment: @Jesus, its best if you ask other questions on StackOverFlow, the point is to share knowlege, and your questions/answers are probably worth sharing. Just post another question :)